# Spring 3.0.6 MVC @PathVariable and @RequestParam blank/empty in JSP view

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-annotations

I have been trying to get an incredibly simple controller/view set up, and just can't make it work. In my `web.xml`, I've defined a `<servlet>` called `servlet-context.xml`, which is running ok. In `servlet-context.xml`, I've set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

<...other stuff in here... />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

among other things. My understanding is this is all that's needed to use `@` annotations.

In my controller, I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/student/{username}/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminStudent(@PathVariable String username, @RequestParam String studentid) {
    return "student";
}
```

And in my `student.jsp` view, I have:

```
<p>This is the page where you would edit the stuff for ${username}.</p>
<p>The URL parameter <code>studentid</code> is set to ${studentid}.</p>
```

When I make a request to `http://localhost:8080/application/student/xyz123/?studentid=456`, I get the view I expect, but all the variables are blank or null:

```
<p>This is the page where you would edit the stuff for .</p>
<p>The URL parameter <code>studentid</code> is set to .</p>
```

I suspect it's a problem with the way my `web.xml` or `servlet-context.xml` are set up, but I can't find the culprit anywhere. There's nothing showing up in any logs as far as I can see.

---

Update: I was basing my code off this part of the [spring-mvc-showcase](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/views/ViewsController.java):

```
@RequestMapping(value="pathVariables/{foo}/{fruit}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String pathVars(@PathVariable String foo, @PathVariable String fruit) {
    // No need to add @PathVariables "foo" and "fruit" to the model
    // They will be merged in the model before rendering
    return "views/html";
}
```

...which works fine for me. I can't understand why this example works but mine doesn't. Is it because they're [doing something different](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml) with `servlet-context.xml`?

```
<annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
    <argument-resolvers>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.samples.mvc.data.custom.CustomArgumentResolver"/>
    </argument-resolvers>
</annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aha! Figured it out, finally.

The `spring-mvc-showcase` is using Spring 3.1, which will automatically expose `@PathVariable`s to the model, according to [SPR-7543](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7543).

As pointed out by @duffymo and @JB Nizet, adding to the Model with `model.put()` is the thing to do for versions of Spring earlier than 3.1.

Ted Young pointed me in the right direction with [Spring: Expose @PathVariables To The Model](https://web.archive.org/web/20110520030942/http://tedyoung.me/2011/01/24/spring-expose-pathvariables-to-the-model/).

Answer (score 17):

Create a Model map and add those parameter name/value pairs to it:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/student/{username}/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminStudent(@PathVariable String username, @RequestParam String studentid, Model model) {
    model.put("username", username);
    model.put("studentid", studentid);

    return "student";
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! I've added an example from the Spring developers - I'd really appreciate it if you could explain why theirs works.

Answer (score 4):

`@PathVariable` means that the annotated method argument should be extracted from the path of the invoked URL. `@RequestParam` means that the annotated method argument must be extracted from the request parameters. None of these annotations cause the annotated arguments to be put in the request, session or application scope.

`${username}` means "write the value of the username attribute (found in page, or request, or session, or application scope) in the response". Since you didn't include any username attribute in any of those scopes, it doesn't write anything.

The code would work if the method returned a ModelAndView object, and the model contained a `username` attribute and a `studentid` attribute.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! I've added an example from the Spring developers - I'd really appreciate it if you could explain why theirs works.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, then, and Spring automatically adds path variables to the model. The reference doc says that such path variables work only if cebugging is enabled during compilation. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates. Try with @PathVariable("username") and @PathVariable("studentid")

Answer (score 1):

- `@PathVariable` is to obtain some placeholder from the uri (Spring call it an URI Template)
  — see [Spring Reference Chapter 16.3.2.2 URI Template Patterns](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)
- `@RequestParam` is to obtain an parameter — see [Spring Reference Chapter 16.3.3.3 Binding request parameters to method parameters with @RequestParam](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

Assume this Url `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/user/1234/invoices?date=12-05-2013` (to get the invoices for user 1234 for today)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{userId}/invoices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Invoice> listUsersInvoices(
            @PathVariable("userId") int user,
            @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) Date dateOrNull) {
      model.put("userId", user);
      model.put("date", dateOrNull);

}
```